Is it possible to support PiP on android without split screen and pop-up view?
I have an SDK that I work on and we have support for Picture in Picture mode because it's a video application. However, we do not want to support split screen and pop-up view.
According to Google, picture-in-picture, split-screen, and pop-up view are the 3 types of multi-window options.
What I'm wondering is if it's possible to allow system PiP without allowing split screen and pop-up view. Can I disable the other two while still allowing system PiP to work?
Currently, I have
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
  android:launchMode="singleTask"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
  android:exported="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
  android:resizeableActivity="false"
>

in the manifest but that still allows split-screen and pop-up view to happen.
